# what's the differences between (variable).toFixed(2) and +(variable).toFixed(2)?

Tags: javascript

I'm wondering what's the main differences between

```
(2.3444).toFixed(2) ==> 2.34
```

Also

```
+(2.3444).toFixed(2) ==> 2.34
```

Both of them giving the same results. Can any one explain when I need to use that + sign?

Comment: `Both of them giving the same results.` do they? If you run them, the first returns `"2.34"` the second returns `2.34` which is both not the same value and also not the values you showed in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first gives you a string, the second gives you a (now truncated) number.

```js
var x = 2.344;
var a = x.toFixed(2);
var b = +x.toFixed(2);
console.log(a, typeof a);
console.log(b, typeof b);
```

A unary plus will attempt to [convert it's operand to a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus).

The reason this matters is because the first one will lead to string concatenation if you "add" a number to it.

```js
var x = 2.344;
var strNumber = x.toFixed(2);
console.log(strNumber);
console.log(strNumber + 5); // Expected: 7.34, actual: 2.345
```